# Why the less matching overloaded method is called

Tags: java, overloading

The result of running the main is:

```
"Collection<?>".
```

Why is it not calling the method with `ArrayList<Integer>` parameter?

```
import java.util.*;
public final class GenericClass<T> {
private void overloadedMethod(Collection<?> o) {
    System.out.println("Collection<?>");
}

private void overloadedMethod(List<Number> o) {
    System.out.println("List<Number>");
}

private void overloadedMethod(ArrayList<Integer> o) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList<Integer>");
}

public void method(List<T> l) {
    overloadedMethod(l);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericClass<Integer> test = new GenericClass<Integer>();
    ArrayList l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    test.method(l);
}
}
```

Comment: I believe it should also be `method(ArrayList<T> l)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will match with second method i.e. `overloadedMethod(List<Number> o)` if you change `Number` to generic type `?` like following:

```
private void overloadedMethod(List<?> o) {
    System.out.println("List<?>");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `l` is a `List`, the only matching function is the first one. Overload resolution is done at compile time, not run time. The value of `l` isn't taken into account, only its type.

As far as the language is concerned, this might as well be:

```
List l = foo();
test.method(1);
```

It doesn't care what value `l` has.

Comment: please refer to the comments below my post; there's more to it, doesn't work even when we change `l` to be an `ArrayList<Integer>` so that the types appear to be exactly the same.

Comment: @Kos: The question was changed and my answer applies to an earlier version of the question.

Answer (score 3):

`overloadedMethod(ArrayList<Integer> o)` doesn't fit because the declared type of parameter `l` is `List` not `ArrayList` and overloading isn't done with respect to dynamic types.

`overloadedMethod(List<Number> o)` doesn't fit as well because the generic type arguments don't match. Java doesn't have covariant or contravariant generics like C#, so `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` don't exhibit a subtype relation.

The best overload is hence `overloadedMethod(Collection<?> o)`, since the other two don't match.

Comment: By mistake i changed the code.
There should be  ArrayList l = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and the result was the same.

Comment: Mmm you're right, this _is_ suspicious :), please edit your question to reflect the issue so that smarter people than me will notice what the real issue is

Answer (score 0):

This resolution is performed at Compile time:

The type of l is List

but it cannot be matched to

List & ArrayList because 'T' is not same as specific 'Number' and 'Integer'

It can only be matched to another generic type '?' and a super class 'Collection'

So in this case resolution is not decided by Data structure but by generics.